# Status no sistema de notícia

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um sistema de notícias e ele é derivado do status, se $status = Ativo ele aparece e se $status = Inativo ele não aparece, como posso fazer isso?

```
<?php
$news8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 8") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php $i = 0; while($noticias = mysql_fetch_assoc($news8)){ $i++; ?>
            <div class='noticia'>
                <div class='img' style='background-image: url(<?php echo $noticias['img']; ?>);'></div>
                <div class='titulo'><b><?php echo $noticias['titulo']; ?></b></div>
                <div class='desc'><?php echo $noticias['resumo']; ?></div>
                <div class='info'>
                    <div class='comentarios' title="20 Comentários"></div>
                    <div class='data' title="<?php echo $noticias['data']; ?>"></div>
                    <div class='autor' title="<?php echo $noticias['autor']; ?>" </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `if(status=ativo) {//seu ódigo} else {//menssagem de erro ou assim}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o status estiver na tabela de notícias, use WHERE no SQL:

```
$news8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias WHERE status = 'ativo' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 8") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não explicou se a variável $status, é vinda do MySQL ou do PHP. Se for do PHP:

```
<?php
$status = "ativo";
$news8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 8") or die(mysql_error());
if($status == "ativo") {
?>
?php $i = 0; while($noticias = mysql_fetch_assoc($news8)){ $i++; ?>
        <div class='noticia'>
            <div class='img' style='background-image: url(<?php echo $noticias['img']; ?>);'></div>
            <div class='titulo'><b><?php echo $noticias['titulo']; ?></b></div>
            <div class='desc'><?php echo $noticias['resumo']; ?></div>
            <div class='info'>
                <div class='comentarios' title="20 Comentários"></div>
                <div class='data' title="<?php echo $noticias['data']; ?>"></div>
                <div class='autor' title="<?php echo $noticias['autor']; ?>" </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } } ?>
```

Se não for, siga o exemplo do @Weslley Buback